# is the file that i am editing somehow creating the file error in speller.c?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm taking CS50 and currently on problem set 'speller.c'. Sorry if this is a simple fix, but I'm just getting started in programming and I am bad at spotting bugs in my code.

I've written all of the functions, but when I try to run the program I get "Could not open %s.\n" every time, after looking at my code I have noticed that this print error doesn't come from the file that I am editing (dictionary.c) but in the file speller.c, which we are not supposed to touch.
**.You may not alter speller.c or Makefile**

here is snippet of code that is probably causing the error:

```
// Try to open text
    char *text = (argc == 3) ? argv[2] : argv[1];
    FILE *file = fopen(text, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }
```

and here is the full code:

```
// Implements a spell-checker

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Undefine any definitions
#undef calculate
#undef getrusage

// Default dictionary
#define DICTIONARY "dictionaries/large"

// Prototype
double calculate(const struct rusage *b, const struct rusage *a);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check for correct number of args
    if (argc != 2 && argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./speller [DICTIONARY] text\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Structures for timing data
    struct rusage before, after;

    // Benchmarks
    double time_load = 0.0, time_check = 0.0, time_size = 0.0, time_unload = 0.0;

    // Determine dictionary to use
    char *dictionary = (argc == 3) ? argv[1] : DICTIONARY;

    // Load dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool loaded = load(dictionary);
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Exit if dictionary not loaded
    if (!loaded)
    {
        printf("Could not load %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // Calculate time to load dictionary
    time_load = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Try to open text
    char *text = (argc == 3) ? argv[2] : argv[1];
    FILE *file = fopen(text, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // Prepare to report misspellings
    printf("\nMISSPELLED WORDS\n\n");

    // Prepare to spell-check
    int index = 0, misspellings = 0, words = 0;
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    // Spell-check each word in text
    char c;
    while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, file))
    {
        // Allow only alphabetical characters and apostrophes
        if (isalpha(c) || (c == '\'' && index > 0))
        {
            // Append character to word
            word[index] = c;
            index++;

            // Ignore alphabetical strings too long to be words
            if (index > LENGTH)
            {
                // Consume remainder of alphabetical string
                while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, file) && isalpha(c));

                // Prepare for new word
                index = 0;
            }
        }

        // Ignore words with numbers (like MS Word can)
        else if (isdigit(c))
        {
            // Consume remainder of alphanumeric string
            while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, file) && isalnum(c));

            // Prepare for new word
            index = 0;
        }

        // We must have found a whole word
        else if (index > 0)
        {
            // Terminate current word
            word[index] = '\0';

            // Update counter
            words++;

            // Check word's spelling
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
            bool misspelled = !check(word);
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

            // Update benchmark
            time_check += calculate(&before, &after);

            // Print word if misspelled
            if (misspelled)
            {
                printf("%s\n", word);
                misspellings++;
            }

            // Prepare for next word
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    // Check whether there was an error
    if (ferror(file))
    {
        fclose(file);
        printf("Error reading %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // Close text
    fclose(file);

    // Determine dictionary's size
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    unsigned int n = size();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Calculate time to determine dictionary's size
    time_size = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Unload dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool unloaded = unload();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Abort if dictionary not unloaded
    if (!unloaded)
    {
        printf("Could not unload %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // Calculate time to unload dictionary
    time_unload = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Report benchmarks
    printf("\nWORDS MISSPELLED:     %d\n", misspellings);
    printf("WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  %d\n", n);
    printf("WORDS IN TEXT:        %d\n", words);
    printf("TIME IN load:         %.2f\n", time_load);
    printf("TIME IN check:        %.2f\n", time_check);
    printf("TIME IN size:         %.2f\n", time_size);
    printf("TIME IN unload:       %.2f\n", time_unload);
    printf("TIME IN TOTAL:        %.2f\n\n",
           time_load + time_check + time_size + time_unload);

    // Success
    return 0;
}

// Returns number of seconds between b and a
double calculate(const struct rusage *b, const struct rusage *a)
{
    if (b == NULL || a == NULL)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return ((((a->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_utime.tv_usec) -
                  (b->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_utime.tv_usec)) +
                 ((a->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_stime.tv_usec) -
                  (b->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_stime.tv_usec)))
                / 1000000.0);
    }
}
```

Finally here is the code I am working on:

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

//count the element in dictionary
unsigned int counter = 0;

// TODO: Choose number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 26;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    int index = hash(word);
    node* curr = table[index];
    while(curr != NULL)
    {
        if (!strcasecmp(curr->word, word))
        {
            return true;
        }
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // TODO: Improve this hash function
    return toupper(word[0]) - 'A';
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // TODO
    FILE *file = fopen("dictionaries/large", "r");
    if (!file)
    {
        return false;
    }
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    counter = 0;
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (!new_node)
        {
            fclose(file);
            return false;
        }
        strcpy(new_node->word, word);
        int index = hash(word);
        new_node->next = table[index];
        table[index] = new_node;
        counter++;
    }
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    // TODO
    return counter;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // TODO
    node* curr = NULL;
    node* tmp = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
        curr = table[i];
        while(curr)
        {
            tmp = curr->next;
            free(curr);
            curr = tmp;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I've made some research and couldn't find someone who ran to the same problem so I am very confused and have no idea on how to proceed, Any help and explanations are appreciated. Thank you

Comment: `when I try to run the program I get "Could not open %s.\n"` how do you run program? do you really see `%s`?

Comment: Instead of `printf("Could not open %s.\n", text);` try with `perror("fopen");` and you will get more information

Comment: No if I input 3 args ./speller dictionary/large help, %s is replaced by the third argument if I input 2 args ./speller help, %s is replaced by the second argument

Comment: @DavidRanieri i did and I got, **fopen: No such file or directory **. Doesn't fopen() create a file if it is not available? and how can such an obvious bug be in the harvard curriculum

Comment: @ksm No, if you `fopen` a file for *reading* it is not automatically created.

Comment: @Bodo so should i just edit speller.c and forget about the instructions

Comment: I don't know what you are supposed to do. Maybe you have to create the input file using a text editor, maybe you have to choose the name of a file that already exists, ... What would you expect to read from a file if it would be created automatically by `fopen`? You would get EOF on the first attempt to read because the file would be empty unless you write to it before reading.

Comment: @Bodo Basically I need to complete check, hash, load, size, and unload functions in file dictionary.c (above you can see the code that I have made myself under the //TODO) and shouldn't alter anything in speller.c. but I keep getting the same error from speller.c file, thus i have asked the question above.

Comment: As I understand the usage message `Usage: ./speller [DICTIONARY] text` in combination with the code, the program expects `text` to be an existing file with the text to spell-check. If there is no text file as part of your task, create one using a simple text editor, e.g. the same editor you use to write your source code.

Comment: Citing https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/5/speller/ : **"Be sure to read this specification in its entirety before starting so you know what to do and how to do it!"** ... "So that you can test your implementation of `speller`, we’ve also provided you with a whole bunch of texts, among them the script from *La La Land*, the text of the Affordable Care Act, three million bytes from Tolstoy, [ ...shortened... ] and more. So that you know what to expect, open and skim each of those files, all of which are in a directory called `texts` within your `pset5` directory."

Comment: @Bodo Thank you sir, I skimmed through this part and assumed that text was the word that I should be searching for in the dict file. i guess this will be a lesson for the future

Comment: why using the double quotes in the `fopen`? The name of the file to be opened is passed to the function in the variable `dictionary`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In investigating this project in the past for some other support question, I had downloaded the code and tested it out.  The code above is the same as the code from the download site.  In building the program, following is the location of the compiled program along with the supporting dictionaries and test documents.

[image: Program directory]

My guess is that you may not have identified the document to be tested with the proper path.  When I ran a test of the spell checker program, I utilized a text file within the "texts" folder.

```
    @Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Speller/bin/Release$ ./Speller "dictionaries/large" "texts/birdman.txt"
```

Following are the last lines of the output in the terminal.

```
WORDS MISSPELLED:     1179
WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  143091
WORDS IN TEXT:        21798
TIME IN load:         0.08
TIME IN check:        0.19
TIME IN size:         0.00
TIME IN unload:       0.01
TIME IN TOTAL:        0.28
```

So, the bottom line is make sure the you have entered in the proper directory path with the file in order for the program to locate your file (and dictionary).